# Trigger an action to increment all rows of an int column which are greater than or equal to the inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am performing some insertion to an SQL table with has three columns and several rows of data The three columns are `Id,Product,ProductOrder` with the following data

```
Id Product ProductOrder
1  Dell     1
2  HP       3
3  lenovo   2
4  Apple    10
```

Now, I would like a trigger which fires an action and increments all the ProductOrders  by 1which are greater than or equal to the inserted ProductOrder.

For example, I am inserting a record with `Id=5 Product=Sony, ProductOrder=2` Then it should look for all the products with `ProductOrder` greater than or equal to 2 and increment them by `1`. So, the resultant data in the `SQL table` should be as follows

```
Id Product ProductOrder
    1  Dell     1
    2  HP       4
    3  lenovo   3
    4  Apple    11
    5  Sony     2
```

From above we can see  that `ProductOrder` which are equal or greater than the inserted are incremented by `1` like `HP,Lenovo,Apple`

**May I know a way to implement this?**

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you always inserting a single row or multiple rows?  If you insert multiples, do you want the data incremented once for each record, or just once per insert?  And what is the application of this logic?  It makes no sense to me, is it just for homework?

Comment: Its straightforward .. use an insert after trigger that uses "inserted" and updates the product order.

Comment: @JiggsJedi. I would just be inserting one record at a time. The application of this logic is the way the items are displayed on a webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some TRIGGER listening to insert into the table and update the `ProductOrder` accordingly:

In my demo, I call your table `test`:

```
create trigger test_trigger on test
for insert
as 
 begin
  declare @order int 
  declare @id int
  select @order = ProductOrder, @id = Id from inserted
  update test 
  set ProductOrder = ProductOrder + 1
  where ProductOrder >= @order and Id != @id
 end
```

### [Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59b8c/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this before insert new product:

```
UPDATE TableName SET ProductOrder = ProductOrder + 1
WHERE ProductOrder <= 2
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (5, 'Sony', 2)
```

Also you can create stored procedure for those 2 actions.

Comment: Well, I would not know the productOrder unless I insert one. It can be anything. In the question I just used it as an example

Comment: Ok, so just add `AND` clause in `WHERE` and exclude inserted id.